# Is there a general selector for a specific nth of typ and all nths after?

Tags: css, web-scraping, xpath, selector, parsehub

I am using a data scraper and I know just enough code to not know what I'm doing. The scraper is free and has a crawl limit. There is no option to resume the crawl from end point. I need to scrape all li's on the page. The program will only let me select 1 or all li's. I am trying to come up with a manual selector or xpath that would allow me to select from nth-child(200)on. Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:nth-child()` selector, as you mentioned, and change the functional notation according to your desired rule. You can read more about it and how it works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation).

If you set it to `:nth-child(n+5)`, the selector will select the fifth element in addition to all the elements that come after it:

```css
li:nth-child(n+5) {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>Numbers:</p>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

**I figured it out. For this example x and y are the known numbers**:

```
element:nth-child(n+x)                     = From x forward 
element:nth-child(-n+x)                    = Up to x 
element:nth-child(n+x):nth-child(-n+x)     = Range between x and y
```

**So for this specific example the solution would be**:

```
element:nth-child(n+200)
```